# CNN Object detection and training with watermarked images, will it work?

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, image-recognition, yolo

I was wondering if training a CNN like YOLO for object detection tasks of pandas using watermarked images (with watermark 1.[under the image](https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/panda-bear-sleeping-on-tree-260nw-688280269.jpg) or 2.[over it](https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/panda-bear-sleeping-on-tree-450w-688280269.jpg) or 3.[diffused](https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-panda-bear-sleeping-on-a-tree-branch-china-wildlife-bifengxia-nature-reserve-sichuan-province-688280269.jpg)) would significantly affect the accuracy of the model, when tested against non watermarked images.

Also, more specifically, if the watermark is in the image, but outside of the region of the object I want to detect (like example 1. or eventually 3.), how would this affect the end result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOLO probably will be able to tackle noise problem, but still it's not the best dataset that you can make. For better accuracy I suggest you to use YoloV3-SPP (Spatial Pyramid Pooling) model. You can use SPP model from this popular repo https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet.

In `darknet/cfg/yolov3-spp.cfg` you can see there's SPP block addition :

```
### SPP ### 
 [maxpool] 
 stride=1 
 size=5 

 [route] 
 layers=-2 

 [maxpool] 
 stride=1 
 size=9 

 [route] 
 layers=-4 

 [maxpool] 
 stride=1 
 size=13 

 [route] 
 layers=-1,-3,-5,-6 

 ### End SPP ###
```

SPP uses downsampling (stride=2) in Convolutional layers + use 3 different size max pool to the same image and get the best features in Max-Pooling layers. I think by adding Max pooling layer it will reduce some noises from the image by selecting only maximum values and important features from the image.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Is your suggestion of using the SPP version of YoloV3 a general suggestion vs the simple YoloV3 or is it related to the specific task of better handling of watermarks because of the max pooling layers?

Comment: Not in specific, but in general SPP will give you higher mAP (accuracy) compared to other model, but it has slower inference time (accuracy and speed trade off). So I suggest you to try both model, which one is more suitable for your task.

Answer (score 1):

From experience, I would say that YOLO should be able to handle this level of noise.
Going over your cases:

1. This should not be a problem. Some training routines actually include black white image borders to achieve the correct resolution without stretching the images.
2. and 3. This might be a problem if the watermark masks important features, or worse if part of a watermark is associated with a class during training.

If the watermark is outside the region of the object:
YOLO has the capabilities to learn context across the image, but as long as you stick to pretrained models you should be fine.